# Python Code Injection With int()

Tags: python, exploit-development, remote-code-execution

I discovered reading the documentation for `int()` in python that I could execute operating system commands if something like the following were passed to the `int()` constructor:

```
type('',(),{'a':5,'b':6,'c':7,'__int__':lambda x : exec("import os; os.system('whoami');"),'getB':lambda self : self.b})()
```

[image]

I have a situation at work where my input is passed as a string directly to the `int()` constructor but because I am injecting a string representing an anonymous class and not code representing an anonymous class directly, I am unable to achieve command execution using the above. I was wondering if anyone might know if either:

1. Is there a string that I could pass to the `int()` constructor that would somehow be converted into an anonymous class (i.e. is there any kind of special string notation to represent an anonymous class)?
2. If there is another approach where, given a string that is passed to an `int()` call, could an operating system command could be executed?

I guess even more generally than that, has anyone seen a way to execute any sort of command from a string passed to `int()`?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Do you have the source code?

Comment: @SirMuffington source code of what?

Comment: Of the Python script

Comment: I'm lost: what script?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a string that I could pass to the `int()` constructor that would somehow be converted into an anonymous class (i.e. is there any kind of special string notation to represent an anonymous class)?

A string is simply a sequence of unicode characters (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html). I don't see how this would ever be expected to behave as anything but a string -- or be expected to throw anything other than `TypeError` / become an integer when passed to `int()`.

> If there is another approach where, given a string that is passed to an `int()` call, could an operating system command could be executed?

Not unless your `int()` call is constructed something like `int(eval(<input>))` which changes the question completely. Handling most-any data with `eval()` is not safe and should not be performed in this manner.

> I guess even more generally than that, has anyone seen a way to execute any sort of command from a string passed to `int()`?

I have not. In your example, what you are passing to `int()` isn't a python string, it's python commands, thus why you are able to get it to execute and return `whoami`. From outside the program / from a string variable used in `int()`, I don't think anything of this sort should be possible.

Fundamentally I think you would encounter the same problem with the following command. Runs great if it's interpreted as Python commands (as follows)...

```
int(print(exec("import os; os.system('whoami');")))
```

... but if you are taking in a string, such as with `int(input())`, it would look as follows in your program and would not execute anything.

```
int('''print(exec("import os; os.system('whoami');"))''')
```